# Explode function in Hive not placing output in multiple rows

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

My array string in hive looks like this.

[[a,b],[c,d], [e,f]]

Output should be

```
[a,b]

[c,d] 

[e,f]
```

I tried using explode function and lateral view also.
Am getting the output as [a,b], [c,d],[e,f] in one row. I need the output like having each string in one row as above.

Comment: Check this question                                                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667473/hive-explode-lateral-view-multiple-arrays .

Comment: explode() takes in an array (or a map) as an input and outputs the elements of the array (map) as separate rows. UDTF's can be used in the SELECT expression list and as a part of LATERAL VIEW.   This is how explode is defined in tutorial.  I want to know  if i can get the output with explode without using custom UDFs.