# Hive - Split delimited columns over multiple rows, select based on position

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm Looking for a way to split the column based on comma delimited data.  Below is my dataset

```
id  col1  col2
1   5,6   7,8
```

I want to get the result

```
id col1 col2
1  5    7
1  6    8
```

The position of the index should match because I need to fetch results accordingly.

I tried the below query but it returns the cartesian product.

**Query**:

```
SELECT col3, col4
FROM test ext 
lateral VIEW explode(split(col1,'\002')) col1 AS col3
lateral VIEW explode(split(col2,'\002')) col2 AS col4
```

**Result**:

```
id col1 col2
1  5    7
1  5    8
1  6    7
1  6    8
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive Explode / Lateral View multiple arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667473/hive-explode-lateral-view-multiple-arrays)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `posexplode()` to create position index columns for your split arrays. Then, select only those rows where the position indices are equal.

```
SELECT id, col3, col4
  FROM test
  lateral VIEW posexplode(split(col1,'\002')) col1 AS pos3, col3
  lateral VIEW posexplode(split(col2,'\002')) col2 AS pos4, col4
  WHERE pos3 = pos4;
```

Output:

```
id col3 col4
1  5    7
1  6    8
```

Reference: [Hive language manual - posexplode()](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-posexplode)

Comment: This is extremely inefficient.

Comment: This works only if i have equal size in both the columns. what if we have difference in size after split. we expect null in that case. can u help here