# Hive query to split column data and store into multiple records

Tags: hive, hiveql, impala

Can someone suggest me how to write Hive SQL query with the below details.

- **input:** (tab delimited data)

  `Name   Phone        Address
  abc     123:456:789  hyderabad,bangalore,chennai
  xyz     111:222:333  delhi,mumbai,pune
  pqr     321:654:999  add1,add2,add3`
- **output:**

  `Name   Phone   Address
  abc 123 hyderabad
  abc 456 bangalore
  abc 789 chennai
  xyz 111 delhi
  xyz 222 mumbai
  xyz 333 pune
  pqr 321 add1
  pqr 654 add2
  pqr 999 add3`

Can someone help me how to split the column data and place it as a new record **Without using any default functions**.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667473/hive-explode-lateral-view-multiple-arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are not aware of the pre-defined functions used for this. We can write the custom logic like below (**Only if we know the delimiters and #of splits**).

```
select name, substr(phone,instr(phone,':',1)-1) phone, substr(address,instr(address,',',1)-1)
union all 
select name, substr(phone,instr(phone,':',2)-1) phone, substr(address,instr(address,',',2)-1)
union all 
select name, substr(phone,instr(phone,':',2)+1,length(phone)) phone, substr(address,instr(address,',',2)+1,length(address))
```

This may be helpful if we don't know the predefined methods.

Answer (score 2):

Use [posexplode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-posexplode),split.Since you need the indexes of the split columns to match,you will need to use posexplode to create indexes and ensure they match when you convert the columns to rows.

```
select Name, Phone, Address 
from table 
      lateral view posexplode(split(Phone,':')) Phone AS index1, Phone
      lateral view posexplode(split(Address,',')) Address AS index2, Address
where index1=index2;
```