# Explode is doing cross join in hive

Tags: hiveql, explode, cross-join

My table is like this in Hive:-

### col1    |   col2     |      col3

> C1      |   F1,F2,F3  |     V1,V2,V3

I need output in below format:-

### col1   |  col2    |   col3

> C1     |  F1      |   V1
>   C1     |  F2      |   V2
>   C1     |  F3      |   V3

I used the explode function as below:-

**select col1, exp_col2, exp_col3
from my_table

LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE (split(col2, ',')) col2table AS exp_col2

LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE (split(col3, ',')) col3table AS exp_col3;**

> This query is doing cross join on col1, instead of returning 3 rows it is returning 9 rows as output.

Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: If col1 is a CK/PK then: explode (col1, col2) & explode (col1, col3); join the results on col1. Please read & act on [mcve]. Explain exactly what data could be in the input--Is col1 a PK? Can there be duplicate rows? Make input & code cut & paste & runnable with output diffable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive Explode / Lateral View multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20667473/3404097)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive Explode / Lateral View multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667473/hive-explode-lateral-view-multiple-arrays)